# "Spotlight quit unexpectedly" in MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4, This crash happening after I have installed Xcode 12

Tags: macos, ios14, xcode12

**I have shown below logs repeatedly.**
**This crash happening after I have installed Xcode 12 in MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4**

Any one please help me to fixing this crash.

```
Process:               Spotlight [3454]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Spotlight.app/Spotlight

Identifier:            Spotlight
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [3294]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [2445]
Date/Time:             2020-09-26 07:23:36.460 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.4 (19E266)
Report Version:        12

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/jitendra/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/19E266/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0.18A372
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode 12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot

Time Awake Since Boot: 1800 seconds
System Integrity Protection: disabled
Crashed Thread:        0
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason:    Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM 193.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 1.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Comment: You might want to try Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: @Richard Barber, As of my opinion OS update is not way to fixing this

Comment: I have the same issue on 10.15.7. There is a [Developer Forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660734) on it.

Comment: I had the same problem on 10.15.7. A recommendation from the [Developer Forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660734) mentioned by @jonatan is to uncheck "Applications" from the Spotlight settings. That alone didn't work for me. I ended up unchecking several options, including "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Look up," and haven't had a problem since.

Answer (score -1):

Unchecking "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Look up" did it for me! I had this issue since 10.15.5 and remained until and including 10.15.7. Updates didn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry, only for a few tries. The crashing came back. First time when typing an "s", then constantly. Now it's useless again due to immediate crashes, even before typing anything. Had this issue since a long time. Very annoying!